# When your question is flagged as a duplicate, the edit link appears to not render correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

I posted a question that has since been flagged as a duplicate of an already existing question.

The panel at the top of the question is as you'd expect, apart from the 'edit' link which hasn't rendered properly:

[image]

When I inspect the surrounding div it's obvious the issue is due to the use of entities such as `&lt;`:

`&lt;a id="edit-instead" href="/posts/307773/edit"&gt;I will edit to explain how.&lt;/a&gt;`